# HubSpot form script in NextJS head

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js, hubspot

I'm trying to add the following script to my NextJS Head:

```js
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "XXXXXX",
    formId: "XXXXXX"
});
</script>
```

Then it gives me two errors:

Error 1: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?ts(1381) (for closing bracket)

Error 2: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "}" (for the line "region: "na1")

This is the whole indes.jsx file:

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import styled from "styled-components";
import HeroSection from "../components/sections/HeroSection";
import OverviewSection from "../components/sections/OverviewSection";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin-top: 10rem;
`;

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Head>
        <title>Code Shape - Home</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          id="hs-script-loader"
          async
          defer
          src="//js.hs-scripts.com/8205013.js"
        ></script>
        <script
          charset="utf-8"
          type="text/javascript"
          src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"
        ></script>
        <script>
          hbspt.forms.create(
          {
            region: "na1",
            portalId: "XXXXXX",
            formId: "XXXXXX",
          }
          );
        </script>
      </Head>
      <HeroSection />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

The script is coming from HubSpot when generating the form, so I assumed the script code is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is getting escaped, try and wrap it into the dangerouslySetInnerHTML property:

```
  <Head>
    <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
       hbspt.forms.create({
           region: "na1",
           portalId: "XXXXXX",
           formId: "XXXXXX"
       });
     `}} />
  </Head>
```

Comment: That works really good, but in my case it is rendering the form at the end of the <body> tag, not inside the layout area for it, did I missing something?

Comment: Found my solution... adding the param:  "target: '#id'" after "formId: 'XXXX'" did the trick.

Comment: If somebody stumbles upon this question like I did, know that the "target: '#id' after the formId is mandatory in order to make it work.

Comment: Without the string interpolation, it works but on refresh it says hbspt not defined - Reference Error. With the string interpolation, the form doesn't show at all. What's the way out please?