# How to embed a hubspot form inside a Next JS component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, hubspot, app-router

I have been trying to embed a hubspot form inside a next js component, but no luck yet.
I tried to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67311209/hubspot-form-script-in-nextjs-head), but still couldn't figure it out yet. Where should I put the embed code exactly ?

I'm pretty new to the world of react and Next JS. Can anyone please help me figure this out ?

My Next JS app structure looks like this:

app folder
|
|_ (pages) -> (home) -> page.jsx (imports & displays the component)
|                      -> layout.jsx
|
|_ components folder -> component.jsx

I'm trying to embed the hubspot form inside a div, inside the component

Is this approach wrong ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for a Hubspot form in Next 13 with the app directory, so hopefully the below works for you

Create a client component with a useEffect that creates and appends a script element to the document body then attaches a load event listener targeting the component.

Then import and use the component wherever you like, passing in the relevant props.

components/forms/HubspotForm.tsx

```
"use client";

import React, {useEffect} from "react";
    
const HubspotContactForm = props => {
    const { region, portalId, formId } = props;
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src='https://js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            // @ts-ignore
            if (window.hbspt) {
                // @ts-ignore
                window.hbspt.forms.create({
                    region: region,
                    portalId: portalId,
                    formId: formId,
                    target: '#hubspotForm'
                })
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="hubspotForm"></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HubspotContactForm;
```